# Некорректно срабатывают миграции в yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, foreign-key

При выполнении команды php yii migrate вылетает ошибка:

```
    > create table user ... done (time: 0.438s)
    > create index idx-user-role_id on user (role_id) ... done (time: 0.224s)
    > add foreign key fk-user-role_id: user (role_id) references role (id) ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `user` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-user-role_id` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE'

in D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:676

Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1215
    [2] => Cannot add foreign key constraint
)

Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint'
```

Код:
create_user_table:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Handles the creation of table `{{%user}}`.
 */
class m221217_170029_create_user_table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('user', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'login' => $this->string(),
            'password' => $this->string(),
            'role_id' => $this->integer(),
            'image_id' => $this->integer(),
        ]);

        $this->createIndex(
            'idx-user-role_id',
            'user',
            'role_id'
        );

        $this->addForeignKey(
            'fk-user-role_id',
            'user',
            'role_id',
            'role',
            'id',
            'CASCADE',
        );

        $this->createIndex(
            'idx-user-image_id',
            'user',
            'image_id'
        );

        $this->addForeignKey(
            'fk-user-image_id',
            'user',
            'image_id',
            'image',
            'id',
            'CASCADE',
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropForeignKey(
            'fk-user-role_id',
            'user'
        );

        $this->dropIndex(
            'idx-user-role_id',
            'user'
        );

        $this->dropForeignKey(
            'fk-user-image_id',
            'user'
        );

        $this->dropIndex(
            'idx-user-image_id',
            'user'
        );

        $this->dropTable('user');
    }
}
```

create_role_table:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Handles the creation of table `{{%role}}`.
 */
class m221217_170107_create_role_table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('role', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'name' => $this->string(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('role');
    }
}
```

create_image_table:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Handles the creation of table `{{%image}}`.
 */
class m221217_170056_create_image_table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('image', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'path' => $this->string()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('image');
    }
}
```

[image: Изначально пустая БД. На изображении результат запуска миграций]

Comment: проверьте, что типы связываемых колонок одинаковы, а также что в колонке связываемой таблице нет значений, отсутствующих в основной таблице

Comment: У полей role_id и image_id стоит integer, а у id из таблиц image и role primaryKey

Comment: Все таки надо сначала нужные таблицы создать, потом их связывать. Когда выполняется миграция по пользователям и хотим создать ключи, таблицы ролей еще нет.

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении внешнего ключа не требуется предварительно добавлять индекс на поле. Он создастся автоматически.
В вашем случае в миграции не требуется использовать конструкции

```php
$this->createIndex()
```

и

```php
$this->dropIndex()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]